# Firestore OR issue in rules/query

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have these Firestore rules:

```
match /artists/{artistId} {
  allow read: if ('liveOn' in resource.data || request.auth.uid == artistId);
  // I also tried resource.id instead of artistId ^
  allow write: if false;
}
```

I understand that [for OR queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#or_queries) each clause is checked separately against the rules, and that rules can't be used for filters.

Here's how I'm attempting to query it:

```
const [unsortedArtists = [], loading, error] = useCollectionData(
  query(
      artistsCollection,
          or(
            where("liveOn", "!=", null),
            where(documentId(), "==", auth.uid)
          )
    )
);
```

However this *returns no documents*. If I comment out either one of the `where` clauses, some documents are returned, so I'd expect both clauses to result in the union of those documents.

I think I'm understanding the semantics of `OR` in regards to Firestore rules incorrectly. What am I missing here, and what is the appropriate way to perform this query/structure the rules?

---

**EDIT:** I was accidentally swallowing the following error:

> FirebaseError: inequality filter property and first sort order must be the same: `__name__` and `liveOn`

What does that mean, in this context? Is there some implicit sorting going on?

Comment: Can you try swapping your `where` statements in your query? IIRC `!=` based queries should have their `documentId()` statements first if provided. FYI `documentId()` resolves to the `__name__` field mentioned by the error message.

Comment: @samthecodingman just tried that, same issue. Good to know about __name__ though!

Comment: Righto, the next thing to try is trying `orderBy("liveOn"), orderBy(documentId()), or(where("liveOn", ...), where(documentId(), ...))`